# How to set an item to being edited from a button click in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtreeview

I am trying to create a "Rename" button in a GUI I've been working on. When this button is clicked, I want the selected item to go into "Edit mode", where you can type a new name.

I have gotten to the point where everything works, but I don't know how to set the flags properly in order to go into edit mode from the index. Below is a working standalone example.

In this example, if I have selected the item I want to edit, and press F2, then it goes into edit mode. I want to achieve the same thing when I click the "Rename" button.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()

        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.tree = DataBrowserTree()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree)
        self.resize(QSize(1340, 1080))
        self.show()


class DataBrowserTree(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataBrowserTree, self).__init__()

        datafiles_path = r'C:\Repositories\QDscript\DotGUI\TestProjects\Proj_3\datafiles'

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(datafiles_path)
        self.model.setReadOnly(False)
        index = self.model.index(datafiles_path)
        self.setObjectName('dataBrowserTree')

        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setRootIndex(index)
        self.setAnimated(False)
        self.setIndentation(20)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.setColumnHidden(1, True)
        self.setColumnHidden(2, True)
        self.setColumnHidden(3, True)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dir View")

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == 2:
            self.show_rightclick_menu(QMouseEvent.globalPos())

    def show_rightclick_menu(self, pos):
        self.rightclick_menu = QMenu()
        self.action_rename = QAction(self)
        self.action_rename.setText('Rename')
        self.action_rename.triggered.connect(lambda: self.clicked('rename'))
        self.rightclick_menu.addAction(self.action_rename)
        self.rightclick_menu.move(pos.x(), pos.y())
        self.rightclick_menu.show()


    def clicked(self, click_str):
        if click_str == 'rename':
            index = self.selectedIndexes()[0] # This gets the correct QModelIndex
            print(index) # <PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex object at 0x1823D930>

    def edit(self, index, trigger, event):
        # When F2 is pressed I get:
        #   index --> QModelIndex object
        #   trigger --> 8 (the key code)
        #   event --> QKeyEvent object

        return QTreeView.edit(self, index, trigger, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to override the `edit()` method but use it. On the other hand, instead of overriding the `mouseReleaseEvent` method that overrides the default behavior, the `customContextMenuRequested` signal should be used when setting the `contextMenuPolicy` to `Qt::CustomContextMenu` as shown below:

```py
class DataBrowserTree(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataBrowserTree, self).__init__()

        datafiles_path = r'C:\Repositories\QDscript\DotGUI\TestProjects\Proj_3\datafiles'

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(datafiles_path)
        self.model.setReadOnly(False)
        index = self.model.index(datafiles_path)
        self.setObjectName("dataBrowserTree")

        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.setRootIndex(index)
        self.setAnimated(False)
        self.setIndentation(20)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setSortingEnabled(False)
        for i in (1, 2, 3):
            self.setColumnHidden(i, True)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dir View")

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_rightclick_menu)

    def show_rightclick_menu(self, pos):
        ix = self.indexAt(pos)

        rightclick_menu = QMenu()
        action_rename = QAction(self)
        action_rename.setText("Rename")
        rightclick_menu.addAction(action_rename)
        action = rightclick_menu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))
        if action == action_rename:
            self.edit(ix)
```